# Glass node goes wrong

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, glass

I made a glass node following a tutorial.
At the render view looks very nice, just as I want it.

[image]

But at the final render looks bad with a weird reflection on it.

[image]

This is the node setup

[image]

Somebody help me to solve this please. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check for hidden objects: Alt H. Check for the subdivision modifiers on objects. Looks like there is a rectangular object, which gets subdivded. Subdivision modifiers have differen values for Preview and Render and are easily created by accidentally pressing Ctrl 1.

Comment: Oh yes, you are completely right. Now is solved. Thank you very much.